# Create "Personalize Google News" like menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Google has this cool category selection in the google news section. 
I'm interested in building something similar where a user does the following:

1. starts typing in the in the input box and predefined values appear from which one is selected
2. pressin the [+] button adds it to a list.
3. the user has the ability to delete the categories added.

Similar to google without the need to move sliders or drag categories up and down.

Any ideas or point in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

[image: Personalize Google News]

Comment: What have you coded already? What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

A perfect place to start would be checking out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default) feature.

Then what you could do is set a certain number for each interval of the slider and only show that number of articles for the corresponding category.

Comment: I don't really want to use the slider function or the draggable one.

Comment: @space_balls: Draggable has nothing to do with this. And why are you hesitant about slider? It was made for things exactly like this.

Comment: I don't think that you understand my initial question. I'm basically looking to create something similar to the google "personalise news category selecting" WITHOUT the need to have the sliders. It's not a relevant part of my intended UI. IF I wanted to add weight to the categories selected then I would us the jqueryUI slider feature. How would using the slider help me achieve steps 1,2 & 3 from the question above?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you like what Google does, is try out their Google Closure library.

http://code.google.com/closure/

They have slider and autocomplete support here: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html